# Strimzi MirrorMaker2 Topic restart/reset

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker, strimzi

We're using the Strimzi MirrorMaker2 CRD to replicate data from one Kafka cluster to another.
The replication is now in sync and I've noticed that the topic offset for one topic (with 3 partitions) is not correct, the source has more messages than the target.

What I'd like to do is restart that single topic in MM2 without affecting any of the topics being synced. I couldn't see in the documentation how to restart just one topic, is it possible?

We have around 12 topics being synced and ideally, those wouldn't be affected by the restart.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think Mirror Maker 2 allows you to restart *just for one topic*. It runs as several different Kafka Connect connectors which do different tasks. But they do not have any per-topic instances. You can use [this](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/using.html#proc-manual-restart-mirrormaker2-connector-str) to restart a connector or [this](https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/full/using.html#proc-manual-restart-mirrormaker2-connector-task-str) to restart a task. But you cannot choose a specific topics since each task will be handling multiple of them.